# Why java Set.contains() is faster than String.contains()?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, runtime, hashset

For a problem to find common characters between 2 strings, at first I used the straight forward String.contains() method:

```
static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    boolean subStringFound = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++){
        if(s1.contains(Character.toString(s2.charAt(i)))) {
            subStringFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return subStringFound?"YES":"NO";
}
```

However, it passed most of the test cases 5/7 test cases, but faced time-out for 2 cases which were really long strings.

Then I tried with Set.contains():

```
static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    boolean subStringFound = false;
    HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
        set.add(s1.charAt(i));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++){
        if(set.contains(s2.charAt(i))) {
            subStringFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return subStringFound?"YES":"NO";
}
```

And despite I'm running an additional loop to create a Set, it passed all the tests.
What's the main reason for this significant difference in runtime.

Comment: A HashSet lookup is O(1), making the second way O(n). A String lookup is O(n), making your first way O(m*n). Note that you're making it even slower by transforming your character to a String. Why don't you use `contains(s2.charAt(i))`? And why do you use a String as the return type, instead of a boolean?

Comment: The "YES" / "NO" return may be because it's a problem from HackerRank which specifies this as the output format: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/two-strings/problem

Comment: Your first implementation is O(nm) and the second one O(n+m), because of the reason mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks. The problem asked to return that way like kaya mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they are different data structures, and the `contains` method is implemented differently on them.

A string is a sequence of characters, so to test whether it contains a given character, you have to look at each character in the sequence and compare it. This algorithm is called [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search), and it takes O(n) time where n is the number of characters, meaning it takes proportionally more time when there are more characters.

A `HashSet` is a kind of [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure. Basically, to test whether it contains a given character, you take the hash of that character, use the hash as an index in an array, and either the character is there (or very near to there), or it isn't. So you don't have to search the whole set; it takes O(1) time on average, meaning the time is roughly the same however many characters there are.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to look at the implementation in the JDK being used, but most likely `String.contains` is a *linear search* but `HashSet.contains` is not. From the [`HashSet` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance)...
>
> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (`add`, `remove`, `contains` and `size`), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.